# ReadFile(m_hComm, &cadena[rebut]==0, 1, &recibiendo, NULL);

Tags: c++, c

good morning to all. I am writing a program to communicate two PCs through null-model serial RS-232 cable. One of the PCs has MS-DOS 5.0 operating system and the other Windows. I need my program to receive information from the one that has MS-DOS. The program is written in c ++. I am compiling it in the IDE DEV-C ++ and it gives me the following error: 71 can not convert `bool 'to` void *' for argument `2 'to` BOOL ReadFile (void *, void *, DWORD, DWORD *, _OVERLAPPED *) '. If someone has the answer, please let me know.
The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <afx.h>
#include <afxwin.h>
#define STRING_SIZE 100
#define Nombre1 "datahemat.txt"
FILE *fp;
int b = 10;
using namespace std;
unsigned long rebut = 0, recibiendo = 0;
char cadena [512];
int i = 0;
int main(void)
{
/* Este módulo se encarga de abrir el puerto serial para comunicarse*/
    HANDLE m_hComm;
    DWORD dwBytesRead;
    DWORD dwBufferSize;
    TCHAR szBuffer [STRING_SIZE];
    dwBufferSize = sizeof(TCHAR) * STRING_SIZE;
    m_hComm = CreateFile("Com1",GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (m_hComm == (HANDLE)-1){
        printf ("Error abriendo el puerto serie COM1");
        /* return; */
    }
    /* Este módulo de encerga de configurar el puerto segun el protocolo
    Beckman Coulter */
    DCB dcb;
    dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
    GetCommState(m_hComm, &dcb);
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = ODDPARITY;
    dcb.fParity = TRUE;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
    SetCommState (m_hComm,&dcb);
    fp = fopen(Nombre1, "w");
    //Chequeando si el archivo existe.
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("El Archivo no pudo abrirse para escritura\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Archivo Creado\n");
    }
    fprintf (fp, " %d ", b) ;
    fclose(fp);
    do {
        rebut = 0;
        do {
            ReadFile(m_hComm, &cadena[rebut]==0, 1, &recibiendo, NULL);
            if (cadena[rebut]==0) break;
                rebut+=recibiendo;
        } while (rebut<512);
        f.Write(Cadena, rebut);
    } while (rebut==512);
    cout << " Se leyeron " << dwBytesRead << " bytes. " <<"Buffer; " <<           szBuffer << endl;
    CloseHandle (m_hComm); 
}
```

Thanks every body!!!...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `==0` from that line, i.e.:

```
ReadFile(m_hComm, &cadena[rebut], 1, &recibiendo, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! its works... but now i have an error on line 83... the line is:      f.Write(cadena, rebut); the error is: 83 Serial.cpp `f' undeclared (first use this function)